# Does Firebase charge multiple writes on the same update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This might be a somewhat trivial question, but I'm trying to minimize my write operations in a Firebase app and wanted to check on my current code. Let's say I have a Firebase collection that looks like this:

```
conversations
  - someConversationId (<--document)
    - someMessageId1 (<-- object within document)
      - text: "Hey, what's up?",
      - dateSent: new Date(2020, 1, 1),
      - sentBy: "someonesUserId"
    - someMessageId2 (<-- object within document)
      - text: "Not much",
      - dateSent: new Date(2020, 1, 2),
      - sentBy: "someoneElsesUserId"
```

In this case, the `messageId` is the `key`, and the `value` is an `object` with a number of properties.

There are a couple ways I could update the above document. Consider the following two:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("conversations").doc("conversationId").update({
  someMessageId1: {
    text: "New text",
    dateSent: new Date(2020, 1, 2),
    sentBy: "someNewUserId"
});


firebase.firestore().collection("conversations").doc("conversationId").update({
  someMessageId1.text: "New text",
  someMessageId1.dateSent: new Date(2020, 1, 2),
  someMessageId1.sentBy: "someNewUserId"
});
```

My assumption is both methods would result in 1 write operation. Is this right?

**Why I'm asking this**

I have a document with an object within it. In that object are, say, 5-10 properties. I would like to be able to overwrite some of those properties in the object without overwriting the entire object, because on the front end I will only know 2-3 of the properties I'll want to update and I want to keep the rest of the properties. The first method above would overwrite the entire object and leave it with only 3 properties and the others would be erased (I think?). The second method would only overwrite the 3 properties specified and any other properties on the object would remain. But I want to know how many write operations I'll be performing in this instance, and may rearrange my database structure if the second method above counts as 3 writes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many fields you change per update, or the way you express that those fields should be updated.  It's still just one document written per call to `update()`, which costs one write.